# Execute WPF Element validation in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

How can I force validation when user clicks button?

One would think this should be easy, since always you have to do something if the element values are valid.

```
private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // How can I force the validation here? So that empty values are not allowed (validator doesn't allow those)

    if (Validation.GetHasError(textBoxURI) ||
        Validation.GetHasError(textBoxName)) // These return valid values if user has not changed values in fields.
        return;

    DialogResult = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

As you can guess, the empty value is invalid according to my validator (if I type something to textbox) then empty it and blur the focus it will show invalid value.

*As a side note: `UpdateSourceTrigger` won't affect the related problem that initial values are not validated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call UpdateSource on the BindingExpression.  This an example with a textbox, where we force validation to occur:

```
BindingExpression exp = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
exp.UpdateSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using **MultiTrigger**  or **MultiDataTrigger**?

Using this you can define your present rule...and anyother validation rule you may come up with.

[Check this out:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger_members.aspx)

Comment: I did read about it yes, someone made some conditional to stop the "ok" button being enabled using those...

Comment: If you do know how to set DialogResult to true using MultiTrigger do tell, I had a hard time doing that.